# Backup LVM snapshots and Grub2 problem

Tags: grub2, backup, lvm

Long story short, I'm using [obnam](http://obnam.org) to take backups of my system.

This is what I do:

1. take LVM snapshot of `/`, `/usr`, `/boot`, `/var`, `/home`
2. mount the snapshots on `/bck-snapshots`, `/bck-snapshots/usr`, `/bck-snapshots/boot`, `/bck-snapshots/var`, `/bck-snapshots/home`
3. run the backup of snapshots:

   ```
   obnam backup \
       /bck-snapshots \
       /bck-snapshots/usr  \
       /bck-snapshots/boot \
       /bck-snapshots/var  \
       /bck-snapshots/home \
   ```
4. once the backup finishes, umount snapshot filesystems mounted in step 2.
5. remove the snapshots

**Problem**

during the backup, a system update was done, with a new kernel installed and all the grub2 update dance. Now when I try to remove the root snapshot (step 5.) I get this:

> device-mapper: remove ioctl on  failed: Device or resource busy

because the snapshot root device is busy and used by another process:

```
$ sudo lsof /dev/dm-6 # This is the root snapshot device.
lsof: WARNING: can't stat() fuse.gvfsd-fuse file system /run/user/1000/gvfs
      Output information may be incomplete.
COMMAND    PID USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE   SIZE/OFF    NODE NAME
grub-moun 9160 root    3r   BLK  252,6 0t36339712 5295479 /dev/dm-6
```

**Questions**

1. I guess that to lvremove the snapshot I have to stop `grub-mount` to use the device. How to do that safely?
2. I think that the backup snapshot has been added to grub as a viable option to show in the grub menu shown at boot time. What if I remove the corresponding snapshot?
3. Any way to prevent grub from adding the root snapshot found on /bck-snapshots ?

I have to reboot the system in order for the updates to be active, but first I have to know the answer to these questions.

Comment: see `info grub`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [grub-mount](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/natty/man1/grub-mount.1.html) is trying to edit a read only file system and has hung.

It should be safe to send a signal with `kill` to ask it to give up (send `15`, and if needed after a few seconds `2`, and if needed after a few seconds `1`, if it's still running use `-9` and report it to the maintainer) (if the pid number changes start with 15 again )

It's likely to exit non-zero which may effect scripts waiting on it, but the only thing you can do about that is file a bug report and ask the maintainer to have it skip read only file systems.

Note that there are some [related bugs](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/grub2?field.searchtext=grub-mount) they are working on.

Answer (score 1):

Just kill that leftover grub-mount process. This happened to me as well, and there was no apparent negative side-effect to the killing, because the relevant update-grub process had already abandoned it - you can easily verify that by seeing how it the leftover grub-mount process no longer has a parent.